# Is it possible to forward the mail object in Action Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, action-mailbox

We're currently letting users email each other without seeing each other's actual email addresses (double blind) by letting them send emails to `username@parse.example.com` which works great.

```
class ForwardsMailbox < ApplicationMailbox
  before_processing :ensure_users
 
  def process
    content = mail.multipart? ? mail.parts.first.body.decoded : mail.decoded
    UserMailer.with(sender: sender, recipient: recipient, subject: mail.subject, content: content).forward_email.deliver_later
  end
 
  private 
  def sender
    @sender ||= User.find_by(email: mail.from.first)
  end
  def recipient
    @recipient ||= User.find_by(username: mail.to.first.split('@').first)
  end
  def ensure_users
    bounce_with UserMailer.invalid_user(inbound_email) if sender.nil? or recipient.nil?
  end
end
```

Is it possible to forward the whole `mail` object instead of extracting its contents, checking if it is multipart etc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to give this a shot.  Reuse the mail object in your `process` method and directly deliver the message yourself.  You'll need to reach into ActionMailer to get your delivery methods configured correctly, but I believe it'll work.

```rb
def process
  mail.to = sender.email
  mail.from = recipient...
  ActionMailer::Base.wrap_delivery_behavior(mail) # this sets delivery to use what we specified in our rails config.
  mail.deliver # This delivers our email to the smtp server / API
end
```

How this works:

Behind the scenes Mailers are just calling `deliver` on a `Mail` object  to send emails.  You can go peruse through `ActionMailer::MessageDelivery` if you'd like to see that in action.  We're just using that functionality directly here.

I'd recommend staying away from using Mailers in this instance because copying over all the fields from your original mail object to the mailer's mail object is going to require a lot of trial and error.

One thing to note: the headers remain unchanged when the message is re-delivered, so things like `Message-ID` will still be the same (which may or may not be a problem, just something to consider).

Last, if you're concerned at all about `deliver` being a blocking call to an API/SMTP server like I was, worry not!  It looks like ActionMailbox already ensures that the `process` method runs via ActiveJob, so you shouldn't have to worry about an SMTP/API request taking a while and blocking a web request (see [ActionMailbox guides](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailbox_basics.html#what-is-action-mailbox-questionmark)).

Comment: this works perfectly! thank you so much. I wasn't looking forward to figuring out how to forward attachments but wrapping the `mail` object seems to forward attachments correctly as well

Comment: Woohoo!  So glad it worked for you.  Yeah, I believe when I was doing something similar and discovered this pattern, I loved that everything nicely came along :)

Comment: Thanks heaps! The method `wrap_delivery_behavior` saved the day xD